# Angular2: Inject a non @Injectable class

Tags: typescript, angular

angular: 2.0.0-beta.9

Is it possible to inject a non `@Injectable` class into a `component` ? For example, this class could come from a Third party library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. In fact the `@Injectable` decorator isn't to specify that a class is injectable into other ones but that you want to inject something in it at the level of its constructor.

If you don't want to inject something in your class, it's not mandatory to add the `@Injectable` decorator. This class can be injected into other ones.

I think that this Github issue could help you:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4404

What is important here is to understand the difference between decorators and annotations. Here is a great article on this subject:

- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/03/the-difference-between-annotations-and-decorators.html

Answer (score 2):

I think yes it is possible. I have tested it without `@Injectable` decorator and it works fine.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZBeSPqf4HUwLOeWSNfZJ?p=preview)

***AuthService.ts***

```
 import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
 import {Http, Response,HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
 import 'rxjs/Rx';
 import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

 export interface sharedObject{
  firstName:string;
  lastName:stirng;
 }


export class AuthService{
  user:sharedObject;
  constructor()
  {
    console.log('AuthService started')
    this.user={firstName:"micronyks",lastName:"shah"};
  }

  change() {
    console.log('change to angular2');
    this.user.firstName="micronyks1";
    this.user.lastName="shah1";
  }     
}
```

---

If you wonder, because some class, use DI in the constructor and do not use `@Injectable()`. Because this decorated @, for example `@Components`.

> The HeroesComponent has an injected dependency too. Why don't we add
>   @Injectable() to the HeroesComponent?
>
> We can add it if we really want to. It isn't necessary because the
>   HeroesComponent is already decorated with @Component. TypeScript
>   generates metadata for any class with a decorator, and any decorator
>   will do.

For more info you can read this [link Angular page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#why-injectable-)

Comment: Oh thanks for the suggestion. But now if someone likes my answer would see your comment too and will get to the right direction :-)

Comment: Oh great man ! Why don't you edit my answer and link to angular.io. I will accept your edit :-). I'm in some work so can't do it as expected immediately. :-)

Comment: no problem but surely you can do better than me, because my English is very bad, you can review and edit if you do not like good luck

Comment: I dont have an option to give you +1 else I would have done it. But many thanks for indicating the right thing :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the class has dependencies you still can use it in DI. Just provide a factory for it

If you want to be able to inject a class that itself has dependencies (constructor arguments) but don't want or can't apply `@Injectable()`, then you can use a factory instead

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    SomeDep, 
    provide(SomeType, {useFactory: (dep) => new SomeType(dep), 
        deps: [SomeDep]})
]);
```

You can create variables for such providers to make them easily reusable without this cumbersome declaration (like for example `HTTP_PROVIDERS`)

```
export const SOME_TYPE_PROVIDERS: any[] = [
  SomeDep, 
  provide(SomeType, {useFactory: (dep) => new SomeType(dep), 
      deps: [SomeDep]})
];
```

and then use it like

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [SOME_TYPE_PROVIDERS]);
```