# angular 2 (click)= not working on selectors outside of its component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple component that should control the display classes on my datatables. The only way I can get it to work is have the datatable load inside the actual component. The buttons don't work on datatables in other components. I am importing the class and putting in the directive but it's still not seeming to work outside it own nested scope.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgClass} from 'angular2/common';
import {DataTable} from '../../components/datatable/datatable';
import {TestDatatable} from "../../views/grids/testDatatable";
@Component({
    selector: 'show-parent',
    inputs: ['isDisabled'],
    directives: [NgClass, TestDatatable],
    template: `
        <i class="fa fa-sitemap" (click)="toggleOpen($event)"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-th-large" (click)="toggleSplitScreen($event)"></i>


 //The buttons work on this datatable below but if I move 
 //  this selector somewhere else it no longer works

        <myDatatable [ngClass]="{'panel-open': isOpen, 'panel-split':
        isSplit}" class="parent-grid"></myDatable>   
     `
})
export class ShowParent {
    isOpen = false;
    isSplit = false;

    toggleOpen(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    }

    toggleSplitScreen(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.isSplit = !this.isSplit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if this will be the best way to achieve what you seek but can make use of [DI](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html) for that, you can read more [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html)

```
import {SharedSer} from 'yourPath/sharedSer';
..//

bootstrap(AppComponent, [SharedSer]);
```

if you add `[SharedSer]` inside bootstrap, you will have available the same instance for the entire application, no need to use `providers: [SharedSer]`

---

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedSer {

    //In this class, you can implements for example:
    //  get and set keyword, you'll access it like a property. or
    //  get and set method/function.

    isOpen:  boolean = false;
    isSplit: boolean = false;

    constructor() {

    }
}
```

---

```
import {SharedSer} from 'yourPath/sharedSer';
..//

export class ShowParent {

    constructor(private service: SharedSer) {

    }  

    toggleOpen(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.service.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    }

    toggleSplitScreen(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.service.isSplit = !this.service.isSplit;
    }
}
```

---

```
import {SharedSer} from 'yourPath/sharedSer';
..//

export class YourDatatable {

    constructor(private service: SharedSer) {

    }          
}
```

---

Maybe this help you [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397) to better understand services.

sorry for my English and I hope it helps you

Comment: @ndesign11 I am happy that will help you, on the other hand this answer / question is new I think you can clarify some things -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060825/angular2-inject-a-non-injectable-class/36061014#36061014

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because other components can't see the `isOpen` and `isSplit` properties.

Basically you just need to access `isOpen` and `isSplit` in another component.

The easiest way is to create a shared service and then have `isOpen` and `isSplit` be properties of that service. Import the service wherever you need it and access the properties.

There are other options if only a parent component needs access. You can use the `ViewChild` decorator. You can also create an event the parent can listen to, and then use that to set it's own `isOpen` and `isSplit` properties.