# TypeScript decorators defined in separate file

Tags: typescript, angular

(The question is about Typescript and Angular2, I promise ;])

I've done a lot of code in Symfony2 which uses annotations.
In Symfony and Doctrine annotations are optional, you can configure entities mapping, routing and any other stuff using yaml, xml or plain PHP.

This was useful for preparing code which was to be used as separate library. I can prepare my code to be symfony-free, I can then create a bundle which integrates it with symfony. I can still use annotations if I'm not planning to use that code outside symfony.

And then I started learning Angular2 and TypeScript. There are decorators used to do anything. Decorators for component metadata, for services, everything.

So If I want to create a service which would be used with my app I have to mark it as injectable. What if I'd like to prepare a class which could be used with any framework.

Is that possible to add decorator separately (in some sane way) so I can inject an external class to Angular2's DI.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you need to use the `@Injectable` decorator if you want to inject something into your class. This means that you rely a bit of Angular2 since you want to use its dependency injection ;-)

You can inject class into something else without this decorator if you don't want to inject something in it...

See this question for more details:

- [Angular2: Inject a non @Injectable class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060825/angular2-inject-a-non-injectable-class/36060997#36060997)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to inject a class that itself has dependencies (constructor arguments) but don't want or can't apply `@Injectable()`, then you can use a factory instead

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    SomeDep, 
    provide(SomeType, {useFactory: (dep) => new SomeType(dep), 
        deps: [SomeDep]})
]);
```

You can create variables for such providers to make them easily reusable without this cumbersome declaration (like for example `HTTP_PROVIDERS`)

```
export const SOME_TYPE_PROVIDERS: any[] = [
  SomeDep, 
  provide(SomeType, {useFactory: (dep) => new SomeType(dep), 
      deps: [SomeDep]})
];
```

and then use it like

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [SOME_TYPE_PROVIDERS]);
```